# Como actualizar un campo float o int de una entrada? - Django

Tags: django, update, float

Hola amigos disculpen la molestia, pero quiero actualizar un campo Float de mi base de datos pero me aparecen errores de que no se puede.

Mi modelo es el siguiente:

**models.py**

```
class Model1(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, null=True)
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True)
    number = models.FloatField(default=0)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)

    class Meta:
        ordering = ['-created']
```

**views.py**

Lo hice de 2 maneras:
- Esta es la primera

```
def actualizar1(request):
    user = request.user
    obj = Model1.objects.all().filter(user=request.user).first()
    number1 = obj.objects.get('number')
    number1 = 20
    number1.save()
```

Y me da el siguiente ERROR

> AttributeError: Manager isn't accessible via Model1 instances

Ahora esta es la segunda y me da el siguiente error:

```
def actualizar1(request):
    user = request.user
    number1 = Model1.objects.all().filter(user=request.user).first().number
    number1 = 20
    number1.save()
```

Pero me da este ERROR:

> AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'save'

Entonces no se porque sucede esto, gracias por su ayuda!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Prueba asi:

```
def actualizar1(request):
       user = request.user
       user_obj = Model1.objects.all().filter(user=request.user).first()
       user_obj.number=20
       user_obj.save()
   ...
```

Comment: Excelente si funciono amigo gracias!!!

Answer (score 0):

Sé que ya tienes una respuesta aceptada a esta pregunta, pero quiero responder solo para explicarte lo que estaba sucediendo.

En la **primera** forma que intentaste tenías este fragmento de código:

```
obj = Model1.objects.all().filter(user=request.user).first()
number1 = obj.objects.get('number')
```

Lo que quiere decir que `obj` viene siendo una instancia de la clase `Model1`. El atributo `objects` es un atributo de clase y no de instancia, por lo que acceder a el desde la instancia arroja un error, esa es la razón de tu primer error, cuando a la instancia `obj` le llamas el atributo `objects` que es de la clase.

En la **segunda** forma que intentaste tenías este otro fragmento de código:

```
number1 = Model1.objects.all().filter(user=request.user).first().number
number1 = 20
number1.save()
```

Lo que hiciste fue: Consultar en la base de datos la tabla llamada `Model1` y entre todos sus registros filtrar los que sean de un usuario específico, obtener el primero (o el último, de acuerdo a tu `ordering` en el `Meta` de la clase) y acceder a su atributo `number` que al guardarlo en una variable llamada `number1` solo estás guardando un objeto de tipo `int` o `float` de acuerdo a como Django parsee los datos. Por lo tanto tu variable `number1` es un objeto numérico y no un objeto que tu creaste ni que tenga métodos o atributos de base de datos como lo sería una clase que herede de `django.db.models.Model`. Luego en tu procedimiento, sobreescribes la variable `number1` a `20` y por último llamas al método `save()` sobre un entero, al ser así, no funciona de la forma adecuada.

Entonces ¿Cuál es la mejor forma?

La mejor forma sería como te explican en la otra respuesta:

```
obj = Model1.objects.filter(user=request.user).first()
obj.number = 20
obj.save()
```

De esta forma, al hacer la consulta en la base de datos, estamos guardando en la variable `obj` una instancia de la clase `Model1` que sí hereda de `django.db.models.Model` por lo que tiene todos los atributos y métodos de su padre, al hacerlo así, ya podemos modificar directamente el atributo `number` del objeto, y por último, para guardar nuestros cambios, llamamos el método `save` para asegurar que se guarden en la base de datos